# Boost Build runtime-link incompatible properties

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to re-build the boost libraries on a debian 10 64 bit system I have built boost 1.72 before, but am trying to revert back to 1.62 and am getting this error when attempting to compile.

```
error: Name clash for '<p/usr/local/lib>libboost_system.a'
error: 
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having 
error: these incompatible properties:
error: 
error:     -  <runtime-link>static
error:     -  <runtime-link>shared
error: 
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these 
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

I am attempting to compile with the following options:

`./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries --with-libraries=system,log,program_options,filesystem,chrono,regex,thread,date_time,atomic`

`./b2 install --clean-all -a warnings=all toolset=gcc link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --build-dir=Build stage -d+2 --hash cxxflags=-fvisibility=hidden variant=release cxxflags=-fPIC cxxflags=-std=c++14 -sNO_BZIP2=1  || true`

I have run a search for libboost_system.a it does not exist on the system, I am not setting the runtime-link property elsewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that `system` should be built as a `shared` library. You could try removing it from you `b2` command and build it separately with `link=shared`.

Comment: @kenba I dont think this is a case, this builds on a clean install - I just need it to work on my dev machine